# Template Directory Path

Tags: python-2.7, django-1.5

I'm new to python. I'm using python 2.7.1 with django 1.5.1.

When I put this code:

`TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`

in my `settings.py`, the terminal shows the following error:

```
File "/home/pipo/Desktop/mysite/mysite/settings.py", line 116, in <module>
    [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Can someone tell me the reason for this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To fix this error:

```
File "/home/myUser/path/to/project/projectName/projectName/settings.py", line 116, in <module>
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

I had to add this line at the beginning of `settings.py`:

```python
import os
```

Then I get this error:

```
File "/home/myUser/path/to/project/projectName/projectName/settings.py", line 116, in <module>
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
NameError: name 'BASE_DIR' is not defined
```

To fix this, I added this line to `settings.py`:

```python
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

This will return the current file path. You might need to change the `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` part accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change

```py
DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

in `settings.py` into

```py
[BASE_DIR/'templates']
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error:

```
File "C:\Users\shahi\telusko_projects\telusko\telusko\settings.py", line 57, in <module>
  'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Just add this line in the top of `settings.py`:

```python
from pathlib import Path,os
```

Answer (score 0):

This how I make it work:

```
import os
...
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
...
TEMPLATES = [
{
    ...
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/templates')],
    ...
},]
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to import os:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-----------------------------------------'
```